# Keyboard event | SFML I When I press the key, it is read twice

Tags: c++, events, keyboard, sfml

I have this header:

```
void keyboardControl(sf::Event event) {
    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
        if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up) {
            std::cout << "Pressed Up" << std::endl;
        }
        if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Enter)
            std::cout << "Pressed Enter" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

code int main.cpp:

```
    int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WND_WIDTH, WND_HEIGHT), "SFML", sf::Style::Default);
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            keyboardControl(event);
        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `keyboardControl` function is called in the same place in `main.cpp`, when you press the (<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>) keys in the console, the message is displayed once, at the same time when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it is displayed twice, what could be the error?

[image]

P.S. Now that I've edited the code, any press of the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key leads to a double output in the console

Comment: What exactly is displayed twice?

Comment: Note that `KeyPressed` happens both the moment that a key is first pressed _and repeatedly when a key is held_ for the same reason that holding the 'a' key while in a text editor types multiple `a`'s. Are you interested in knowing _the instant when a key is first pressed_ or are you interested in knowing `_is a given key being held down right now_?

Comment: I am interested in the moment of pressing, not holding, in all cases (when I click on Up, Down and other) the console displays information once, but it is with Enter twice

Comment: Please [edit] your post and read about and create a [mcve]. Right now, all function parameters except `event` appear to be unrelated, and we can't rule out from the code you've shown that you've made a mistake elsewhere, for example where you call `pollEvent`. You should be able to get your example down to 50 lines of code or less with the same results.

Comment: @alterigel igel, Done

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, that clarifies things a lot. Currently, your `keyboardControl` function means, `whenever any key is pressed { if that key is Up { print "Pressed Up" } Then, if the Enter key is also being held down { print "Pressed Enter" } }`. Do you see the difference? Is this what you want? Why aren't you using the same code for both `Up` and `Enter`?

Comment: @alterigel I've edited the code, but nothing helps, it still appears twice in the console

Comment: I tried running your code on Windows and I can't reproduce your problem. If I briefly tap either Up or Enter, I see only a single print statement. If I press and hold the key, I see multiple print statements after a slight delay, just like in a text editor. How long are you holding the keys down for and what's the key repeat delay set to in your system settings?

Comment: I don't hold down the key, and the Windows settings are standard

Comment: Try a different keyboard. Try starting from scratch and running the exact code that you posted. The problem is not in the code you've shown.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, it turns out I had a keyboardControlfunction, and also its body separately (I used it for verification and forgot to comment). Thank you all very much!